# Adding a simulation zone mess up previous nodes

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

I'm trying to animate the opening of a book (especially the pages), and the pages turning. For some reason, I can't add a simulation zone without messing up my current node tree. As if it was cancelling some nodes before it (like Set Position). **That's my current problem**, but my setup being a bit complex, I have to explain it as below.

The blend file : [image]

First here is the book, before and after opening :
[image: Main setup at start of animation]

[image: Main setup at end of animation]

My geometry nodes are a bit on the heavy side, here are the nodes followed by informations :

[image: Geometry nodes setup]

---

To explain all that, here is an annoted version of my setup with the main steps :

1. Generate a vertical array of horizontal curves (i.e. the profile of each page)
2. Move left-most handles to follow the book opening (using a rotating empty)
3. Trim the curves to keep a given length (here 21cm)
   Then I want to add on top of that, the animation of pages turning. That would the step 4 which I want to place between 2 and 3 (blue arrow). I'm pretty sure I **need** to use a simulation zone (indepent animation of each page, animation that must changed along time).

[image: Annoted geometry nodes setup]

And then, with only the addition of a simulation zone, the step 2 is completely ignored. But not the step 1.

[image: Adding a simulation zone mess up some other nodes]

I've got to say, I have no idea why. I'm used to Blender but I think I'm missing something.

1. Why is the simulation zone cancelling some nodes but not all ? Am I missing some obvious thing ?
2. Is my way of doing things wrong ?
3. Should I put **everything** inside a Simulation Zone ?

Thanks a lot for reading me :)

Comment: Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Comment: I edited my post with the blend file.

Comment: As I understand it, every nodes that are upstream the *Simulation Input* node and linked to its *Geometry* socket are executed once (at iteration 0 ?). Then the geometry is recycled inside the *Simulation Zone*. Every nodes that are downstream the *Simulation Output* node are executed after each iteration. So to get the curves deformed by the *Empty*, you have to bypass the *Geometry* socket of the *Simulation Input* node. Instead, plug it directly "inside" the *Simulation Zone*. To start with, plug it directly to the "inside" *Geometry* socket of the *Output* and you recover the animation.

Comment: Merci bien ! I get your point, I will try that. Thanks :)